LlamaIndex Embeddings Pydantic Error: Cannot Import Embedding Library
from llama_index.core.settings import Settings



Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(

    model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"

)



embeddings = Settings.embed_model.get_text_embedding(

    "It is raining cats and dogs here!"

)



print(embeddings)

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\pyfiles\newapp1\New folder\embedllama.py", line 1, in  from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\embeddings\huggingface_init_.py", line 1, in  from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface.base import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\embeddings\huggingface\base.py", line 11, in  from llama_index.core.base.embeddings.base import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core_init_.py", line 19, in  from llama_index.core.indices import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices_init_.py", line 4, in  from llama_index.core.indices.composability.graph import ComposableGraph File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\composability_init_.py", line 4, in  from llama_index.core.indices.composability.graph import ComposableGraph File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\composability\graph.py", line 7, in  from llama_index.core.indices.base import BaseIndex File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\base.py", line 10, in  from llama_index.core.chat_engine.types import BaseChatEngine, ChatMode File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\chat_engine_init_.py", line 1, in  from llama_index.core.chat_engine.condense_plus_context import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\chat_engine\condense_plus_context.py", line 8, in  from llama_index.core.chat_engine.types import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\chat_engine\types.py", line 19, in  from llama_index.core.tools import ToolOutput File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\tools_init_.py", line 6, in  from llama_index.core.tools.query_plan import QueryPlanTool File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\tools\query_plan.py", line 6, in  from llama_index.core.response_synthesizers import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\response_synthesizers_init_.py", line 3, in  from llama_index.core.response_synthesizers.accumulate import Accumulate File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\response_synthesizers\accumulate.py", line 12, in  from llama_index.core.response_synthesizers.base import BaseSynthesizer File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\response_synthesizers\base.py", line 49, in  from llama_index.core.instrumentation.events.synthesis import ( File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\instrumentation\events\synthesis.py", line 15, in  class SynthesizeEndEvent(BaseEvent): File "pydantic\main.py", line 198, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.new File "pydantic\fields.py", line 506, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer File "pydantic\fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.init File "pydantic\fields.py", line 552, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare File "pydantic\fields.py", line 663, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis File "pydantic\fields.py", line 808, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._create_sub_type File "pydantic\fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.init File "pydantic\fields.py", line 557, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare File "pydantic\fields.py", line 831, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators File "pydantic\validators.py", line 725, in find_validators File "pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 479, in make_dataclass_validator elif f.default is not MISSING: File "pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 231, in pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass class Field: File "pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 218, in pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass.wrap return InitVar(type) File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1021, in dataclass return wrap(cls) File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1013, in wrap return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash, frozen) File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\dataclasses.py", line 927, in _process_class _init_fn(flds, File "C:\Users\NakaMura\anaconda3\lib\dataclasses.py", line 504, in _init_fn raise TypeError(f'non-default argument {f.name!r} ' TypeError: non-default argument 'source_nodes' follows default argument
It shows what I tried above.
